# delete the self folder once execution completed

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I was able to delete the script once the execution completed.

```
function Delete() {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    $Path =  $Invocation.MyCommand.Path 
    Write-Host $Path 
    Remove-Item $Path
            }       
Delete
```

But am unable to delete the entire folder and subfolder from where the script is running. Is there any way to get around this which works on both powershell2.0 and 3.0?

Comment: To delete subfolders and whatnot you'll need to add the `-Recurse` parameter to `Remove-Item`.

Comment: You may not be able to delete the folder where the script is located, because the script file may be in use at the time. In addition, your current location (`(Get-Location).Path`) should not be the folder you wish to delete.

Comment: In my experiments, even on PowerShell 2 you can delete a script file in the very first line and it will continue processing the script. It appears to read the whole thing into memory and then run it from there.

I have a script that relies on this as it's on a network and can be running on up to 4 workstations, doesn't stop me saving over it with an updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to use the `-recurse` and `-force` parameter. Also you have to get the script folder using e. g. `Split-Path` cmdlet:

```
function Delete() {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    $Path =  $Invocation.MyCommand.Path 
    Write-Host $Path 
    Remove-Item (Split-Path $Path) -recurse -force
            }       
Delete
```